# REST development plugin for browser with all HTTP methods

Tags: user-interface, rest, browser-extension

Is there a plugin for any web browser which gives you a GUI to perform PUT's, DELETE's etc? I've written a navigable REST app, and I would like to be able to poke around a bit with my browser to try it out and to demo the API, but since they all lack DELETE and PUT it becomes cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several FireFox plugins for that, including "Poster" and "REST client".

Comment: These ones are alright, but their interfaces are completely non-integrated with the main engine, so you cannot follow html links etc. I would prefer something that adds PUT and DELETE to the normal UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can poke around easily by serving http://www.aminus.net/wiki/Okapi alongside your regular site content. It allows not only DELETE and PUT, but *any* custom method. In addition, you have complete control over the headers.

It's a "meta-browser" of sorts, so not really good for a user- or exec-oriented demo. But it can sure help you see exactly what is being sent and received, and debug problems more quickly. It makes a great tool for other developers to discover your non-HTML RESTful apps, too.