# Can one send a PUT or DELETE HTTP request using the browser?

Tags: web-services, http, rest, browser

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [REST development plugin for browser with all HTTP methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751568/rest-development-plugin-for-browser-with-all-http-methods)
>   [Are the PUT, DELETE, HEAD, etc methods available in most web browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers)

How does one tell a web browser to send a PUT or DELETE request? I know I can tell it to send a POST or GET request by changing the form method property. It seems that this feature wouldn't be hard to implement.

I just read the famous article "How I explained REST to my wife" http://tomayko.com/writings/rest-to-my-wife. Needless to say, I had a suspicion before and I am now convinced that RESTful is the best way to design a web application.

Are browsers really not implementing PUT and DELETE? If so, why? What are the design considerations that go into this? Furthermore, are there plans in the future for these features to be integrated into browsers and other web standards?

Are major browsers already implementing the full set of HTTP features? And if they are, how do I ask them to use those features?

Comment: @Stu, I don't see how this is a duplicate of that question. Would you please explain?

Comment: Hi Tom, you're right. Sorry, this was a C&P error, the question I intended to reference was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers

Comment: @Stu: Now I see that it is really duplicate and my answer was not needed.

Comment: @Ladislav well, it was still nice of you, I didn't find the actual question when I searched. Thanks Stu.

Answer (score 3):

It is not about browsers but about version of HTML used to define the form - both HTML 4.01 a XHTML 1.0 (I'm not sure about HTML 5) supports only GET and POST as method of HTML form. If you want to use PUT and DELETE you must either use JavaScript and `XMLHttpRequest` directly or some JavaScript library which simplifies this (like jQuery).